# Redux action to reset - states are equal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reducers

I have the following initialState For React Redux:

```js
const inistialStateRedux = {
  configuredFilters: {
    data: {
      countries: [],
      divisions: [],
      companies: [],
      locations: [],
      fields: [],
      search: '',
    },
  },
};
```

Now I want to create a RESET reducer.

It looks like that:

```js
export const createReducer = (initialState, handlers) => (
  state = initialState,
  action
) => {
  if (action.type in handlers) {
    return handlers[action.type](state, action);
  }
  return state;
};

export const multiUse = (reducer, name = '') => (state = null, action) => {
  if (action.name !== name) return state;

  return reducer(state, action);
};
```

```js
import {
  createReducer
} from '../helper';
import * as Action from './actions';
import inistialStateRedux from '../inistialStateRedux';

export default createReducer({
  data: {},
}, {
  [Action.RESET_CONFIGURED_FILTERS]: (state) => ({
    ...state,
    data: {
      ...inistialStateRedux.configuredFilters.data,
    },
  }),
});
```

But Redux Devtools shows, that the states are equal. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri why in the action ?

Answer (score 0):

In the Actions you can use a dispatcher to reset the Form.
Like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { ADD} from '../modelType';
import { reset } from 'redux-form'; 


export const add= formValues => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.post('/api/model/', { ...formValues });
  dispatch({
    type: ADD,
    payload: res.data
  });
  dispatch(reset('yourUniqueFormName'));
};
```

Comment: I don't use redux-form at all.